# sum values didn't calculate using order +=

Tags: php, loops, sum

i just try to use sum with my loop
so i created this code to run first sql command to get value from MYSQL

```
$money = 0;
foreach ( $fullticketsdetails as $fullticketdetails ) 
{
    echo $fullticketdetails->TKT_sold;
    echo $fullticketdetails->TKT_price;
    $moneydo = $fullticketdetails->TKT_sold *  $fullticketdetails->TKT_price;
    $money+= $moneydo;
}
echo $money;
```

Now the result must be: `ex = money1 + money2` (1590+775=2365)

but result is concatenation of strings: `ex = money1money2` (1590775) without going to calculate any values.

Comment: Without actual values to see there's no way to help you

Comment: i just added actual values

Comment: are you trying to do some of multiplication is it ?

Comment: @GaneshKandu yes that it, and so user bill may have 2 different items with different prices so i need and end to collect the total of bill

Comment: @RamyAdel please provide actule value you using for foreach

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `$` in your code. I made a note in the code below.

```
    $money = 0;
foreach ( $fullticketsdetails as $fullticketdetails ) 
{
echo $fullticketdetails->TKT_sold;
echo $fullticketdetails->TKT_price;
$moneydo = $fullticketdetails->TKT_sold *  $fullticketdetails->TKT_price;
$money+= $moneydo; //The missing $ is on this line for 'moneydo'
}
echo $money;
```

Comment: i add $ but value is still "1590775" as "money1money2"

Answer (score 0):

please provide detail its working for me

```
<?php

class aaa{

    function __construct($a,$b){
        $this->TKT_sold = $a;
        $this->TKT_price = $b;
    }
}

$fullticketsdetails = array();
$fullticketsdetails[] = new aaa(1,2);
$fullticketsdetails[] = new aaa(5,6);

$money = 0;
foreach ( $fullticketsdetails as $fullticketdetails ) 
{
    $moneydo = $fullticketdetails->TKT_sold *  $fullticketdetails->TKT_price;
    $money += $moneydo;
}

echo $money;
```

answer is **32**

```
32 = 1*2 + 5*6
```